# how to get mysql rows on month basis

Tags: mysql, rows

I am in a problem and i am confused. I have a table for events and in it there is a column that holds the timestamp of the date time when it was created. I want to get all events(rows) that were created in this month, the last month, and 2 more month before the last month. So, basically 4 months. I want to show them separately so, i can think i can query the datebase for all rows in this month in one query and another query for previous month and so on for 4 months. The problem is i don't know how can i do that. There is a month() function in mysql but i am lost, no idea how to use it.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Edit: table structure is like this.

```
Title  | Uri  | created

Event  | Event| 1337782223
name   | uri  |  
.......
```

**EDIT 2**

Thanks all for your help..
I tried it myself and with my friend google...:)
I used this

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) = $month;
```

and this seems to work for me, i will just pass the month whos rows i want from php thats easier for me...lol

Thanks again to all for your answers its appreciated. This place is awesome

Comment: Exactly how would you want the result to look?

Comment: simple i want all rows that were created in this month in one query and in another query i want all rows that were created last month and so on for 4 months

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From your_table Group By Month(column_with_date);
```

Of couse you have to have a timestamp column in your table.

If not then it's impossible to restore the informations when the entry was inserted.

Comment: what about previous month can we use something like this
Select * From your_table Group By Month(column_with_date) - 1;

Comment: Yes,
you then need sth. like
Select * From your_table WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) <= column_with_date

Answer (score 0):

```
$month = '5,4,3,2';
select colum_name from table_name where month(table_field_name) IN ($thismonth) Group By month(table_field_name)
```

try this one if you are using separate query for each month

```
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
$thismonth = strtotime($todayDate);
 $previous_month =  mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"), date("Y"));
```

and you can get past months just do minus NUMBER ex -2,-3 .....for current month

```
select colum_name from table_name where month(table_field_name) = month ($thismonth) AND year(table_field_name) = year ($thismonth)  Group By month(table_field_name);
```

for previous month

```
 select colum_name from table_name where month(table_field_name) = month ($previous_month ) AND year(table_field_name) = year ($thismonth) Group By month(table_field_name)
```

Comment: Some conversion from timestamp to datetime might be needed, but something like this would work.

Comment: ya but one month in one query and another in another query

Comment: Don't forget that MONTH only returns month. If you want to seperate by year as well, you need to group by year also. So that 2011-06 is not confused with 2012-06.

Comment: Ya you are right. will add another Where clause for year. Thanks